# Dynamically add multiple columns in a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to dynamically add multiple radio buttons in a panel in a winform from the data abstracted from a text file. But when I load the application, only a single radio button is displayed in the panel. Can anyone help me? Here is the code for my project

```
string NewFilePath = "E:\\Tables.txt";
string[] Records = File.ReadAllLines(NewFilePath);
foreach (string items in Records)
{
    RadioButton a = new RadioButton();
    a.Click += new EventHandler(a_Click);
    a.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
    a.Font = new Font("Cambria", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
    a.Width = 75;
    a.Height = 50;
    a.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
    a.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    a.Name = items;
    a.Text = items.ToString();
    a.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    a.BackColor = Color.White;
    a.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    pnlCustomrdb.Controls.Add(a);
}
```

Comment: Could it be because you're not setting their position and all of them are appearing on top of each other?

Comment: Use a FlowLayoutPanel instead.

Comment: @dotNET is right. Try to use no foreach loop, but for. And increase top position with formula a.Top = (i+1) * 60.

Comment: you forgot to set the Top property in your loop.